# Using JSLint in Java/GWT

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, error-handling, jslint

I'm currently working on a project in Java, that will allow users to type Javascript code into a GWT Widget. How would I go about importing/using JSLint to check for errors? I looked around and found LSLint4Java, but I couldn't find the way to import it into eclipse. I just need a simple JS error checker that will check a string for errors.

If anyone has any other suggestions for error checking, please share them!
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSlint javascript source can be found [here](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/). You could include the javascript in your WAR, reference it with a script link in your page(s), and make JSNI calls from/to your GWT code.

Note that JSLint has a *No Evil* clause in it's license:

> // The Software shall be used for Good, not Evil.

[Here's](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI) a good start on JSNI.

Comment: Thanks, I can't seem to find a Google tutorial on GWT JSNI calls, is there any tutorial you would recommend?

Comment: first google result for `JSNI`: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI. Note the blurb about 2.5 vs. 2.4, but it doesn't look like this doc has changed much. This is the only info that I've needed to implement similar interaction w/ 3rd-party javascript. But it **can** get complicated. Post new questions if you get stuck.