# GWT check if provided String is valid script

Tags: javascript, gwt

Is there any way to validate script in `GWT`? Currently I am catching exception

```
try {
            result= apply(NativeUtils.createFunction("return " + script), ctx);
        } catch (JavaScriptException e) {
           //do other stuff
        }
```

NativeUtils:

```
public static native JavaScriptObject createFunction(String script) /*-{
        return new Function(script);
    }-*/;
```

But I don't feel comfortable silently catching exception.

Comment: I don't think there's something like script-validation implemented. But as an alternative approach you could use **regex** to check basic integrity of that script, or use an **external validator** via request -  this approach may be very time consuming in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it might be helpful

[Using JSLint in Java/GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11440076/using-jslint-in-java-gwt)

http://jshint.com/docs/

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/jshint.html